# Export Azure Application-Insight Dependency Event,Trace and Exception in Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-application-insights

I am beginner of the azure portal , I configured the Azure Application insight in front-end side (Angular 5) 
and Back-end side (Asp.net core) .

I can track my application log file through azure application insight,
Then i followed the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-code-sample-export-sql-stream-analytics

As per the link they are creating "PageViewsTable" for storing the Page View data,But i need to store the all the dependency in different table like

1,"Event Table"

2,"Exception Table"

I don't know what are the Fields i need 
to create the Table for the Database for storing the all the dependency Tables.If anyone knows What are the Fields need
to use for creation of the All the Dependecny Tabel,It will more Helpful for me ,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following link shows the data model for all types of telemetry including Exceptions, Events etc.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-export-data-model